# Compiled sha256 lib for mysql but it produces other hash than dovecot's sha256

Tags: mysql, hash, sha256

I need to "teach" mysql server to use sha256 algorithm.
I downloaded source from http://stuge.se/mysql-sha256/mysql-sha256-3.tar.bz2, compiled and put in /usr/local/lib/mysql/plugin/. Then i created function in mysql

```
mysql> create function sha256 returns string soname 'sha256.so';
```

It went fine but mysql and dovecot produce different hashes.

```
[root@taz /usr/ports/mail/postgrey]# mysql -u root -p -e "SELECT sha256('test')"
Enter password:
+------------------------------------------------------------------+
| sha256('test')                                                   |
+------------------------------------------------------------------+
| b1499ffe49c3b4f354e30349bca8e62f08604eab6b687322df47d4f8fce76f19 |
+------------------------------------------------------------------+

[root@taz /usr/ports/mail/postgrey]# doveadm pw -s SHA256.hex -p test
{SHA256.HEX}9f86d081884c7d659a2feaa0c55ad015a3bf4f1b2b0b822cd15d6c15b0f00a08

[root@taz /usr/ports/mail/postgrey]# doveadm pw -s SHA256 -p test
{SHA256}n4bQgYhMfWWaL+qgxVrQFaO/TxsrC4Is0V1sFbDwCgg=
```

Why hashes are different? MD5 and SHA1 hashes are same, only SHA256 are different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the command line, I get this result:

```
echo -n test|sha256sum 
9f86d081884c7d659a2feaa0c55ad015a3bf4f1b2b0b822cd15d6c15b0f00a08  -
```

which leads me to believe that dovecot gives the correct answer (I also tried an [online sha256 calculator](http://www.xorbin.com/tools/sha256-hash-calculator) which gives the same result).

That probably means there is a bug in the source code you downloaded. Get in contact with the person who wrote this `mysql-sha256-3.tar.bz2` and let them know of the bug.

Comment: I guess you didn't read my post. I used both b64 and hex and they both don't match